# How to convert screenshot Base64 directly in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

Using following code we can take a screenshot in Cypress

cy.screenshot('abc.png');

But my requirement here is to get Base64 string of the screenshot. Is there any way to directly convert a screenshot to Base64 string in cypress?
(I dont even need to store the screenshot on file system)

Comment: I don't know if cypress has an inbuilt method for this, but you could use something like [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) to intercept the fs write call that the `cy.screenshot` function internally calls